# Move breadcrumb before sort by feature of toolbar section in Magento2

Tags: blocks, xml, breadcrumbs, category-listing

How to move breadcrumb of category list page into toolbar section of category list page.

I need to move the breadcrumb to toolbar or either left sidebar before the filters.

Is it possible to do like that? Please anyone suggest me. Below code i used to move breadcrumb.

```
<move element="breadcrumbs" destination="content" before="-" />
```

from above code i am able to move it before the toolbar, but i need to move it into side bar.

Like this i want it.[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: yes, i have attached the screenshot. please check once

Comment: Did you move your toolbar section to top of main content area?

Comment: no, i used only above code to move breadcrumb

Comment: Where it currently showing after your code?

Comment: It is showing before the toolbar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83618/discussion-between-sukumar-gorai-and-jafar-pinjar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the below file to your theme location:

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

and replace the below block:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml">
    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
</block>
```

with:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml">
    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs" before="-"/>
    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
</block>
```

Copy the below file to your theme location:

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/toolbar.phtml

and update the code with below:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
/**
 * Product list toolbar
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
 */
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\ProductList\Toolbar;
?>
<?php if ($block->getCollection()->getSize()): ?>
    <div class="toolbar toolbar-products" data-mage-init='<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getWidgetOptionsJson() ?>'>
        <?= $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
        <?php if ($block->isExpanded()): ?>
            <?php include ($block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar/viewmode.phtml')) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php include ($block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar/amount.phtml')) ?>

        <?= $block->getPagerHtml() ?>

        <?php include ($block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar/limiter.phtml')) ?>

        <?php if ($block->isExpanded()): ?>
            <?php include ($block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar/sorter.phtml')) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
```